# Permission denied: '/var/log/graphite/info.log'

Tags: apache, ubuntu, graphite, user-permissions

I have launched an Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS, and I have connected to it via ssh using the default AWS user "Ubuntu".

I have followed the instructions on [HERE](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-and-configure-graphite-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to install Graphite on Ubuntu (with mysql).

After the installation when I go to http:// I get HTTP 500 error.
Loogin at the  /var/log/apache2/graphite-web_error.log I see this error message:

mod_wsgi (pid=5835): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi'.

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/graphite/info.log'

I have tried both:

sudo chmod www-data:www-data  /var/log/graphite/info.log

and 
 sudo chmod ubuntu  /var/log/graphite.info

I also have tried chmod:

sudo chmod o+r /var/log/graphite/info.log

Then I have reloaded apache2, but I still get the same error.

Once none of these worked I updated the carbon.conf file and removed the _graphite user from USER entry. Did not help.

This has already wasted two days of my time. I have tried almost every link I found on Google. I am sure there is another problem but the module fails to write the error message into the log file so I need to get the permission problem fixed first. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod` is to set the permissions of the file and `chown` is for changing the owner. Try the following

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/graphite/info.log
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/graphite/info.log
```

Link to docs
[CHMOD](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) [CHOWN](https://ss64.com/bash/chown.html)